# Replace truecrypt container with bitlocker vhd

Tags: truecrypt, bitlocker

Right now I'm have truecrypt mount a container file at startup.  All that is needed after log on is the truecrypt password and then the container mounts.  It stores any personal data on my work machine:  Firefox profile, evernote database, dropbox etc..

Has anyone tried replacing this with an automount bitlocked vhd on startup?  If so how did you automount?  Any performance gains?

It's not that I don't like the truecrypt method, I'm just wondering if having the native app would be better.

Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you may want to read this article and understand the different tools they are using:

http://blogs.sans.org/windows-security/2009/11/17/bitlocker-attached-vhd-drive/

In a nutshell:

- Create the VHD, and mount it as a volume
- Use BitLocker To Go encryption, optionally with your authentication credentials to automount it when you are logged in.